# Spring Boot: "Column 'username' cannot be null" on @manytoone join column

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, postman

I'm trying to post the following json file into mysql database in postman.

```
{
    "rem_month": 3,
    "rem_day":  23,
    "description": "Happy birthday!",
    "username": "mortykrox93"
}
```

But i keep getting the error "Column 'username' cannot be null"

The app is supposed to allow me to login and add multiple reminders for each user.

Here is the sql files the entities are supposed to model:

**user.sql**

```
USE `login-reminder`;

CREATE TABLE `user` (
`email_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`password` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**reminder.sql**

```
USE `login-reminder`;

CREATE TABLE `reminder` (
`rem_num` int(12) NOT NULL,
`rem_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`rem_day` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`rem_num`),
FOREIGN KEY(`username`) REFERENCES user(`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here are the two entity files:

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Column(name="email_id")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="theUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Reminder> reminders;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String emailId, String password, String username) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**Reminder.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reminder")
public class Reminder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="rem_num")
    private int remNum;

    @Column(name="rem_month")
    private int remMonth;

    @Column(name="rem_day")
    private int remDay;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    private User theUser;

    public Reminder() {

    }

    public Reminder(int remNum, int remMonth, int remDay, String description) {
        this.remMonth = remMonth;
        this.remDay = remDay;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getRemNum() {
        return remNum;
    }

    public void setRemNum(int remNum) {
        this.remNum = remNum;
    }

    public int getRemMonth() {
        return remMonth;
    }

    public void setRemMonth(int remMonth) {
        this.remMonth = remMonth;
    }

    public int getRemDay() {
        return remDay;
    }

    public void setRemDay(int remDay) {
        this.remDay = remDay;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Here is the restcontroller.

**ReminderController.java**

```
@RestController
public class ReminderController {

    @Autowired
    private ReminderRepository reminderRepository;

    @GetMapping("/reminders")
    public List<Reminder> getAllReminders() {
        return reminderRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/reminders")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    public Reminder createReminder(@RequestBody Reminder reminder) {
        return reminderRepository.save(reminder);
    }
}
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Not sure if my entities are matching up with my sql statements, any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 0):

Check your reminder sql, it's `username` field is set as not null.
The binding is with the `User` object. So, in your json, it you should send the user like this:

```
{
    "rem_month": 3,
    "rem_day":  23,
    "description": "Happy birthday!",
    "theUser":{
               "username":"mortykrox93",
               //and other fields if necessary
              } 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of there is no field named `username` present in `Reminder` entity class and you are referring to same class in controller with annotation `@requestbody` to be bind with the request. Actually during deserialization no valid mapping is present for json field named `username`. so by default `username` is being set as null because of its datatype string.

**Note**: It's better to use separate model/pojo class for binding the request. And then map it to proper entity objects.

Comment: Thank you, this approach will make it easier for me to implement my code.

Comment: NP @Pmore23. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need change your json that indicates by @user404:

```
    {
    "rem_month": 3,
    "rem_day":  23,
    "description": "Happy birthday!",
    "theUser":
              {
               "username":"mortykrox93",
               //and other fields if necessary
              } 
    }
```

also, the problem is in jackson deserialize, you need to use the anotation for make the relashionship in jackson (is different that Hibernate/JPA) @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference:

In User entity:

```
@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy="theUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Reminder> reminders;
```

In Reminder Entity:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="username")
    private User theUser;
```

Anyway, is recomended use separated DTO classes for transfer data and add in those the jackson annotation. In the entity only use JPA annotations.